# Python Bokeh: How to update a Toggle button - defined in the main - in a subroutine

Tags: python, bokeh, dashboard

I have the following simple bokeh example. The start button starts an infinitive while loop in a subroutine, which should stop running as soon as button 3 is pressed or the checkbox is unchecked. Button2 checks the status without the loop which works fine. As button3 and the checkbox cb are defined in the main the subroutine called by button1 does not recognize the change. Is there a way to solve this?

I used bokeh version 1.0.1. You can run the example lokally with `bokeh serve script.py` and view it in your browser (http://localhost:5006).

```
from bokeh.models import Column
from bokeh.plotting import curdoc
from bokeh.models.widgets import Button, Toggle, CheckboxGroup
import time

def start_loop():
    while (not button3.active) and (len(cb.active)):
        time.sleep(1)
        print(button3.active)
        print(cb.active)

def check_status():
    print(button3.active)
    print(cb.active)

button1 = Button(label = "start")
button1.on_click(start_loop)

button2 = Button(label = "check status")
button2.on_click(check_status)

button3 = Toggle(label="stop")
cb = CheckboxGroup(labels=['stop'],active=[0])

curdoc().add_root(Column(button1,button2,button3,cb))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the while loop interferes the Tornado IO_loop. I advice you to use `add_periodic_callback` instead (Bokeh v1.1.0)

```
from bokeh.models import Column
from bokeh.plotting import curdoc
from bokeh.models.widgets import Button, Toggle, CheckboxGroup
import time

# def start_loop():
#     while (not button3.active) and (len(cb.active)):
#         time.sleep(1)
#         print(button3.active)
#         print(cb.active)

def check_status():
    print(button3.active)
    print(cb.active)

# button1 = Button(label = "start")
# button1.on_click(start_loop)

button2 = Button(label = "check status")
button2.on_click(check_status)

button3 = Toggle(label = "stop")
cb = CheckboxGroup(labels = ['stop'], active = [0])

curdoc().add_root(Column(button2, button3, cb))
curdoc().add_periodic_callback(check_status, 1000)
```

Comment: Exactly. Putting a while loop in a callback blocks *everything*, including processing other property change events.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is, the dashboard is quite large and the while loop is only a small part of it. Adding a periodic_callback is therefore not really possible.unless it would be possible to add the periodic callback only for one of the children.

Comment: In the callback you should do all (and only) Bokeh plots / widgets related updates. For other functions e.g. data acquisition or processing you are free to add another asynchronous threads and access the data in the callback.

Comment: I agree threads will be necessary for any blocking work https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/server.html#updating-from-threads